# Get taxonomy that is attached to post with all its parents

Tags: custom-taxonomy

```
$locations = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'location' ); 

foreach ( $locations as $location ) {

    echo '<a href="'.site_url().'/location/'.$location->slug.'">'. $location->name .'</a>';

    break; 
}
```

---

How to also get all parent taxonomies if there are any?

For example:

1. Current code outputs `London` in front-end.
2. What I would need to output `Europe > England > London`.

---

What I managed to dig up or have tried is that `get_the_terms()` also have `parent` property which could be used as `$location->parent`. This only has ID property, I didn't manage to squeeze name or slug out of it. Also there's no way to use it to retrieve it's parent if it has any.

---

**Update after some experimenting:**

```
//Parent
if( $location->parent != "" ) {

    $location_parent_id = $location->parent; 
    $location_parent = get_term_by( 'id', $location_parent_id, 'location' );

    echo $location_parent->name; //Here it is
}   

//If I need parent of parent
if( $location_parent->parent != "" ) {

    $location_parent_parent_id = $location_parent->parent; 
    $location_parent_parent = get_term_by( 'id', $location_parent_parent_id, 'location' );

    echo $location_parent_parent->name; //Here it is
}

//etc
```

**Is this very *grazy* approach?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [`get_ancestors()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors). This is pretty crude but...

```
$locations = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' ); 
// var_dump($locations);
$pat = '<a href="'.site_url().'/location/%s">%s</a>';
foreach ( $locations as $location ) {
  printf($pat,$location->slug,$location->name);
  $anc = get_ancestors($location->term_id,'category');
  if (!empty($anc)) {
    foreach ($anc as $term) {
      $t = get_term_by( 'term_id', $term, 'category');
      printf($pat,$t->slug,$t->name);
    }
  }
  break; 
}
```

Comment: How is this compared to my approach in question performance wise?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to display your taxonomy in a hierarchy format? This is something that I have done recently. Try something like this

```
// Get all taxonomies that do not have a parent/top level taxonomies
$parents = get_terms( $taxonomy, array( 'hide_empty' => true, 'parent' => 0 ) );

foreach ( $parents as $parent ) {
    echo $parent->name . ': ';
    $child_terms = array();

    // Get all post terms for this post and use the parent ID to grab the children
    $children = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy, array( 'hide_empty' => true, 'parent' => $parent->term_id ) );

        foreach ( $children as $child ) {
            // build a link to the children taxonomy archive
            $child_terms[] = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', get_term_link($child, $taxonomy), $child->name );
        }

    echo implode( ', ', $child_terms) . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: I did look into `get_terms()` but I thought that it's not reasonable (performance wise) to get all taxonomies only to filter those few that are attached to post.